# Impossible to install GoogleAnalyticsTracker.Core Nuget package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I want to install the package GoogleAnalyticsTracker.Core from Nuget in my C++ project, but when I try to install, I get this error:

> Could not install package 'GoogleAnalyticsTracker.Core 4.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'native,Version=v0.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I don't know why it cannot install it, my .NET Framework is v4.5.

This is the nuspec file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>GoogleAnalyticsTracker.Core</id>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <title>GoogleAnalyticsTracker.Core</title>
    <authors>GoogleAnalyticsTracker</authors>
    <owners>GoogleAnalyticsTracker</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>GoogleAnalyticsTracker - A C# library for tracking Google Analytics.</description>
    <copyright>Copyright © GoogleAnalyticsTracker 2012 - 2015</copyright>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Comment: Managed C++ doesn't support NuGet

Comment: It support the Nuget I created myself with lib files, why it doesn't work with this one?

Comment: If your own package put the dll in the `lib/` folder, rather than a `lib/<tfm>` folder, then it's a package layout that's only supported by `packages.config` and not `PackageReference`. Since .NET Core (at least with C#/VB/F# ) only supports `PackageReference`, it's effectively a package layout that no longer works. As the error message says, the project system advertises itself as a `native` assembly to NuGet, so it's not compatible with any .NET Framework or .NET Standard TFMs, when the package uses the `lib/<tfm>` package layout.

Comment: As a work-around, you may be able to use a `packages.config` file not associated with a project to install packages you want using `nuget.exe packages.config -PackagesDirectory somewhere\packages`, but then you need to manually select assets (if a package contains assemblies for multiple TFMs, you have to select the right TFM) and add references to the dlls directly in your project. If the package contains `build/<package_id>.props` or `.targets`, you have to manually edit your project file and import them.